# Narrow SQL results to the owner at the controller (or higher) level rather than the method level

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm doing a project in Asp.net Core 2.1 (EF, MVC, SQL Server) and typically I'm doing something like the following to get records for the current user (i.e. the owner):

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public JsonResult GetOrders()
        {
            string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

            var applicationDbContext = _context.Order
                .Where(m => m.UserID == userId);
               ...etc...
         }
```

However, I was wondering if there's a more broad (to the controller or even more global) way of filtering results to the owner, rather than having to include the piece of code above to each method?

I tried this with no joy:

```
        public OrderController(ApplicationDbContext context, IAuthorizationService authorizationService, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _authorizationService = authorizationService;
            _userManager = userManager;

            string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            _context = context.Where(m => m.UserID == userId);
        }
```

I somewhat understand why that doesn't work. However, basically, my whole project will be refined to the owner and would be nice to just specify that in one place and then know `_context` (or `ApplicationDbContext`? or whatever the proper way is) already includes just the owner records.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) which were introduced in EF Core 2.0 for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to achieve your requirement, one is implementing `Global Query Filters` and another is passing the `UserId` to `Global Query Filters`.

I suggest you follow steps below:

1. Moidfy the DbContexxt

   ```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
   {
       protected virtual string CurrentUserId
       {
           get
           {
               return Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)?.Id;
           }
       }
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
       private readonly UserResolverService _userResolverService;
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options
            , IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor
           )
           : base(options)
       {
           _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
       }
       public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

       private static MethodInfo ConfigureGlobalFiltersMethodInfo = typeof(ApplicationDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(ConfigureGlobalFilters), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           //Configure Query Filter
           foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
           {
               ConfigureGlobalFiltersMethodInfo
                   .MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType)
                   .Invoke(this, new object[] { builder, entityType });
           }

           base.OnModelCreating(builder);            
       }

       protected void ConfigureGlobalFilters<TEntity>(ModelBuilder builder, IMutableEntityType entityType)
                           where TEntity : class
       {
           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = null;
           if (typeof(IEntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
           {
               expression = e => ((IEntityBase)e).UserId == CurrentUserId;
               builder.Entity<TEntity>().HasQueryFilter(expression);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Register `IHttpContextAccessor` by code below

      ```
          services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
      ```
   3. For center controlling the UserId Filter, I defined `IEntityBase`
      //IEntityBase.cs

      ```
       public interface IEntityBase    {
          string UserId { get; set; }
          IdentityUser User { get; set; }
       }
      ```

//Order

```
    public class Order: IEntityBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```